# expo-updates failed to upload error: graphql request failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-updates

After running expo update --auto, I get the error- "graphql request failed" with no context or way to debug it. The build process gets hung up on 52/55 and then says the above error. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XFwy.png) is a picture of what the terminal looks like.

I have double-checked everything through the tutorial, the debugging page, and the advanced debugging page. All of my configuration files are correct. When I go to the deployments page on the expo, I can see my branches are there and are linked to the correct channel, but the branches never receive any updates.

Comment: can you add the expo version you're using? (project and CLI)

Comment: Yes, eas -v shows `eas-cli/3.16.0 darwin-arm64 node-v20.2.0` and expo version is `49.0.3`